wot != "web of trust"
I'd rename wot to web-of-trust, since usually "wot" means "wall of text".

I suppose we could make a synonym, but I can't imagine being confused by [tag:wot] since I can't imagine someone tagging anything as "wall of text"

I agree with David's comment that confusion is unlikely.
Still I like the suggestion as I think that some people won't immediately associate "wot" with "web of trust". They could hover the mouse to see the description but to me that's an unnecessary step as I don't see any downsides of using "web-of-trust" as the tag. Sure, it's a bit longer, but does that really matter?
